# Interleave controller Issue - JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to simulate a sequential call to couple of webservices by putting them under Interleave controller.  Although I have unchecked "ignore sub-controller blocks", jmeter still runs only one of the controllers living under interleave controller and alternates it for each iteration.  What I need is a sequential call to all .

Any help is appreciated.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The Interleave Controller is running as it should do. It **will** alternate through one web service for each iteration

If you want a **Sequential call to both web services on each request**, then just put them directly under the Thread Group - without any logic controller or keep a [Simple Controller](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller)

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, why do you need the Interleave Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Jose

Thanks for the answer. Keeping them directly under thread group did not call them sequentially. You can try it. I currently have about 10 webservices (let us call them 1..10) some are heavy and some are light there by resulting in different response times. However, I would like to run these in order that is from 1 to 10.

Directly placing them under thread group did not call them sequentially, so I used interleave controller with "ignore sub-controller blocks" unchecked.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment on my answer, and not a new answer. Try the Simple Controller - it should work. Interleave usage is incorrect in your case.